# Angular Route vs $Resource

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-resource

So I have a few REST URLs that I would like to load and bind to html when requested.  When user searches for first name and if first name is found html gets populated from json.  This works fine (Initial URL).

**Initial URL**

```
 var url = http://localhost:8080/userSearch/name/find?firstName='+enteredValue.firstName+'&lastName=&
 $http.get(url).success(function(data){
        $scope.dataItems= data;
```

Now using ng-click on first name I want to request address and location based on these URLs

**//URLs**

```
 var url = http://localhost:8080/userSearch/addr/find?address=&address

 var url = http://localhost:8080/userSearch/loca/find?location=&location
```

So I started looking into UI-Router and $Resource.  My first thought is to use $Resource but seems as if others have had problems with ports.

Could I use Router as well to solve this problem or should I stick with Resource?

Comment: `ui-router` and `$resource` serve two totally different problems.  `ui-router` handles routing your in your angular application, not fetching data over HTTP.  A better comparison would be `$http` to `$resource`

Comment: what does `problems with ports` mean? `$resource` is used client side only and has nothing to do with ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui-router and $resource are completely different things. ui-router is used to provide navigation between different states in your app while $resource is used to make calling server side APIs more convenient. If you need to retrieve data from a RESTful backend then $resource is the way to go. I'm not sure what you're referring to about the ports but I've built web applications that service millions of users daily on top of $resource and not had any port problems.

Comment: Thanks Jesse.  Resource it is.